# image overlay on Ti.Map of Titanium

Tags: google-maps, titanium

I am making application on Titanium for iOS and android.

This application uses Ti.Map.

I would like to add image on Ti.Map (google map or apple map)

I have confirmed googlemap API has this function like this below.

[Adding a Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)

I have checked methods of Ti.Map and found createCircle or createPolygon....However these methods are not what I want.

Can I add image as overlay on Ti.Map of Titanium????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `Ti.Map` is very basic and only provides for polylines, polygon and marker additions, but not customizing of the view. If it were possible, it would be only on Android because that is Google Maps.

For your cause, I suggest you add a webview to your app, and use the JavaScript API of Google Maps to fix this. And within this webview add a full size Google Map, so you will not see any borders whatsoever. Should work perfectly fine!

Comment: thank you very much , It's very sorry I cant' use overlay on Ti.map though, I will tray work around way by using polyline.